# Stringbuilder text not displaying on new lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I have a generic html control - a 'P' tag, which i've added a `runat="server"` to.

I construct a string using `Stringbuilder` methods and apply this to the InnerHtml attribute of the tag.

The text,which contains a number of `sb.Appendline()`'s still displays as a paragraph would, wrapping but without creating any new lines. However, When i look at the markup created, the new lines are there, shown as spacing.

This is also the case with a DIV

Anyone got any ideas as to how i fix this?

Code below:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Congratulations!");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendFormat("Your application was accepted by <b>{0}</b>.", response.AcceptedLender);
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendFormat("Your reference number is <b>{0}</b>.", response.PPDReference);
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.Append("Click the button below to sign your loan agreement electronically and collect your cash.");

        AcceptedMessage.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `AppendLine` should use `AppendFormat`:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", strToAppend);
```

If you need these line breaks to remain "as is" because you're displaying it in a text file or something of that nature, you'll need to replace the new line text with html breaks when you're calling the `.ToString()` method.

```
myStringBuilder.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").ToString();
```

Using `Environment.NewLine` here may not work, you may actually need to replace `\r\n`.

Comment: I was just about to post you need to do the new line replacements ;) +1

Comment: @Zonder: It occurred to me after I posted that this may not just be an html only string. Old habits die hard.

Comment: The HTML "<br/>" was what I was missing in my case. I'm constructing emails, so the newline character was essentially useless. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the stringlbuilder newlines (\n) into  BR tags

so that they can be rendered in HTML newlines.

Even better IMO is to enclose the whole lines in P tags

Comment: @Forty-Two: I would give me a -1 for even mentioning the BR tag :-) Yes, I think that P tags should be called the only "right" the way.

Answer (score 0):

The lines appended by StringBuilder does not show in the browser. Browser only recognises 
 and new line. So you have to include the tag for displaying in browsers

```
  sb.AppendLine("some text here <br />");
```

The new lines will show in console applications and not browsers

You can as well replace the new lines

```
AcceptedMessage.InnerHtml = sb.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string messagePattern = @"
<p>Congratulations!</p>
<p>Your application was accepted by <b>{0}</b>.<br />
   Your reference number is <b>{1}</b>.</p>
<p>Click the button below to sign your loan agreement 
   electronically and collect your cash.</p>";

AcceptedMessage.InnerHtml = string.Format(
    messagePattern, 
    response.AcceptedLender, 
    response.PPDReference);
```